# How to use subsections in a c program?

Tags: c, assembly

Code that belongs to the same section but different subsections has its order of placement defined by the subsection number.  I need to use this feature in a c program - i.e. I need two functions to be in the same section and in a particular order.  GCC re-orders functions in the same section as it pleases, so that is why I need subsections.  Here is the syntax for sections - I can't figure out how to specify subsections using the __attribute__ syntax.

```
void func1() __attribute__ ((section ("mysection")));
```

See Jester's comment below for assembly syntax.  I am using gcc, so I am assuming gas assembler?

Here is a long explanation of why I have gotten to the point of needing subsections.  Maybe one of my conclusions along the way was incorrect and you can help me avoid this.

Q: Why not create separate sections and load them contiguously?

A: I have a separate problem where I need to be able to figure out the exact beginning address of my functions ahead of time.

Q: Why do you need to know the address?

A: I want to align some code in my functions (not the function itself) to a particular alignment

Q: Why not use .align?

A: I have found that using .align inside a c function for some reason forces that function itself to be aligned to that value, and I do not want that - so I have come up with an ugly macro alternative to the .align directive:

```
b 1f

. = . + (1 << #alignment") - (("#section_start" + .) & ((1 << "#alignment") - 1))

1:
```

Q: Why not use labels to calculate your current location? Or a label in the loader file?

A: Assembler doesn't let me - I have to use the dot operator.

Q: Tell me again why you need section_start here?

A: The dot operator is relative to the start of the section, it is not the absolute address

Q: Why are you trying this low level stuff in C this is dumb

A: I agree this is dumb, but play along.

Comment: Which assembler/architecture accepts `.section mysection 0`? gas documentation uses `.subsection` for ELF and `.section name, subsection` for COFF (note the comma)?

Comment: You are correct - I removed that part from my question.

Comment: one very good way to place items exactly in the executable file is to pass a `linker command` file to the link step.   Note: a linker command file contains all the `memory` address segments, all the `section` names and which memory address segment that section is to be placed in and the order of the section names within that memory address segment.  you can google `gcc linker command file` to get links to documents that fully describe the file contents

Comment: I am already using a linker file to exactly place my sections.  The problem is that I need two functions to be placed in a particular order, contiguous, and I need to know the exact start address to pass to my align macro.  If they are in different sections the first 2 requirements are met.  If they are in the same section with no subsections the last two requirements are met.  Same section different subsections fulfills all of my requirements.  Note that I can't seem to pass linker labels to my align macro.

Comment: Suggest give each function a different section name (I know of no 'sub section' capability.  Linker names (defined as `. = name` are externs that define addresses that can be referenced from within the C code

Comment: I've found that linker names aren't yet defined when my align macro is created.  I assume that is because we don't know where the section will be placed in the assembler step - we only know section offsets.  The size of my align macro actually depends on where the section is placed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to use subsections, but I believe this GCC option forces function order, and I seem to have at least one example where it fixes the ordering in my test.  I am slightly concerned about having to set -fno-section-anchors as well (seems like you can't only use -fno-toplevel-reorder), but this might be the best workaround I have right now.

One problem with this approach is that I lose the ability to place each function in separate sections - which has the benefit of allowing me to use the linker script to calculate the end of functions (also useful to me).

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

```
-fno-toplevel-reorder -fno-section-anchors
```